# How to stop scheduled method in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, scheduling

There is a Spring MVC application, and it has a

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay=2000, fixedRate=3000)
private void test(){
    System.out.println("foo");
}
```

simple scheduling method. I deployed it into Tomcat and it works. But when I stop the deployed application via Tomcat manager, Tomcat ( catalina.out ) says, there is a memory leak.
I use Spring 4.0.6.

My question is: How do I stop a scheduled method or task ? For example, I want to stop scheduled methods when contextDestroyed method has been invoked.

Here is the Tomcat log :

```
Nov 05, 2014 11:19:35 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/dataservicemodul] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Comment: Spring takes care of that, you should post the tomcat error message

Comment: I added the relevant Tomcat log

Comment: And that has nothing to do with scheduling... But all to do with your datasource implementation used which likely schedules a thread to monitor its connections.